# What information do I get from Spotify's Audio Analysis?

Tags: audio, spotify

When using Spotify's API to analyse a track (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-audio-analysis-track/) it returns a bunch of numbers and strings..

Does anybody know what these numbers are all about and how to interpret them?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Spotify's documentation for the audio analysis:
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-audio-analysis/

If you look at the "track" element, you can see it returns a number of useful stats, such as the tempo, key, mode (minor/major) and loudness of the song. In the "segments" elements you can also get more a detailed pitch and timbral (tonal) analysis for parts of the song.